# Is there a Way to capture Child Process Events from Installer Wizard in ELECTRON?

Tags: electron

My Child Process is an Installer Wizard and I want to close the Main Application(Parent Process) when that Installer wizard(Child Process exec) gets opened,But currently I m getting the output only on complete of that process not when its opening.

This code responsible for opening wizard:

exec(`"${filePath}"`,(error, stdout, stderr) => {
.....callback handler
});

but after opening it doesn't trigger any event to capture that the Installer Wizard is Opened only If I agree to complete the install or I cancel then the callback handler is executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [Node.js documentation on `child_process.exec ()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback), the callback function you supply is only called when the process you have spawned has exited, i.e. has finished its tasks.

To capture the child process' output at runtime, you can use [`child_process.spawn ()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options):

```js
const child_process = require ("child_process");
var child = child_process.spawn (`"${filePath}"`);

child.stdout.on ("data", (data) => console.log (data));   // regular output
child.stderr.on ("data", (data) => console.error (data)); // error output

child.on ("exit", (code) => { /* ... */ }); // child process finished
```

However, unless the process you're calling outputs a specific, recognisable line to its `stdout` (standard output) once it has opened the window, you cannot be certain when the window is open. The process, however, is running once `spawn` has finished.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex spawn worked for me,with  {detached:true} and {shell:true}